# How can I fill a mail chimp form with data from a form on my website on submit?

Tags: html, forms, mailchimp

Ok, so I have a form with 3 fields "Name, Phone, Email" on my clients site and I need people to be able to enter these details and then when they click submit it loads the full external mail chimp form hosted by mail chimp and prefils the 3 fields they already entered on the website itself?

Is this possible?

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do this is to authenticate the the MailChimp API and submit a listSubscribe request: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

Whatever code is handling that form submit should make the connection and return a success or failure. Without knowing what access to that code you have, it is difficult for me to give specific advice, but here is an example of how we did it for php using the MCAPI class provided by the API:

```
<code>function subscribe_init() {
  if(!isset($_POST['subscribe_email'])) {
    redirect();
  }

  $error = $success = FALSE;

  if(valid_email($_POST['subscribe_email'])) {
    $api = new MCAPI('YOUR API KEY HERE');

    if($api->listSubscribe('LIST ID HERE', $_POST['subscribe_email']) === TRUE) {
      $success = TRUE;
    }   
    else {
      ERROR HANDLING HERE
    }   
  }

  return APPROPRIATE MESSAGE
}</code>
```

You'll obviously need to edit that substantially to also include your NAME and PHONE fields.

Comment: Might not be the best idea to have the API KEY in user readable code.

Comment: This is a php snippet. It needs to be implemented by the handler of the $_POST on the server, so it shouldn't be in user readable code. But yes, you are correct, you should never have the API key in user readable code.

Comment: Yeah, don't know what I was thinking it's not js.